# using camera class in android in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

The default camera showing up is the back camera using Camera getCamera
I want to know how to switch to front camera.

Also Camera names length is showing only length as 1 and not 2 , but i am having a front and back camera on galaxy tab, so i think it should show 2 names.

Please let me know a way out to this.

I am using air 3.1 , which is the latest version at present.

and the application is built in Flex 4.6 version

Answer (score 0):

Air for Android only supports the back facing camera -- at least that might have been the case until very recently.

I have downloaded and saved the AS3 API reference from Adobe. On my local copy of the docs, it says this about the Camera.names property:

On Android, only one camera is supported, even if the device has more than one camera devices. The name of the camera is always, "Default."

However, when I look at the docs online, that comment is no longer there. So maybe Air 3.2 (released yesterday) now supports both cameras on Android!

Online docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#names